# How do I join two ElasticSearch indices using elasticsearch-dsl-py?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, dsl

Two indices documents as below:

```
class First(Document):

    class Index:
       name  = 'first'
       
   case_id = Keyword()
   name = Text()
   
class Second(Document):

    class Index:
       name  = 'second'
       
   case_id = Keyword()
   status = Text()
```

I just want to execute a query like below in SQL format

```
select * from first as f, second as s where s.case_id = f.case_id or s.status = 'xyz'
```

How can I do it using elastic search dsl query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Elastic Search doesn't support joins between indexes

   **Reason:** Elastic Search is not relational and denormalized data should be stored here.

   Excerpt from [elastic Doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/joining-queries.html) below :

> Performing full SQL-style joins in a distributed system like
> Elasticsearch is prohibitively expensive. Instead, Elasticsearch
> offers two forms of join which are designed to scale horizontally.

2. Use either nesting or parent/child mapping to store your data, based on the use case.

   **Nesting:** If cardinality of nested doc is very low and indexes are read intensive

   **Parent/child:** If cardinality of child is very high than parent and parent/child needs to be updated frequently

Comment: Or third option: simply denormalize your data